# Save Variable to Disk from outside

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, pickle

I've made a script that saves cache to disk and loads it everytime the file is executed.

-`bar.py:`

```
from cachetools import cached
import pickle

try: 
    with open('mycache.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        cache = pickle.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    cache = {}

@cached(cache)
def df(x):
    return x*x+x


with open('mycache.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(cache, f)
```

The code work well if I call `df()` just after it's initialization and the save the cache, but if I call `df()` from outside it'd be something like this:

-`foo.py`

```
from bar import df

print(df(10))
```

What would I need to do in this case to save the cache to disk after the function `df()` is called?